# Android Fragment Transaction after resuming the application from background

Tags: android, android-fragments

As far as I have understood, When an Activity which underwent multiple transactions was resumed from background(after pressing home button of our device) it will once again recreate all fragments and transactions and restores the fragment state. My question is

*When moving from Fragment A to Fragment B (i.e. adding Fragment B and not replacing Fragment A by Fragment B since I need to maintain it), I paused the webservice calls in Fragment A. Wont this be done when the activity state is restored? If not how can I handle it?*

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.activity_slide_in_from_right, R.anim.activity_slide_out_to_left,R.anim.activity_slide_in_from_left, R.anim.activity_slide_out_to_right);
    Channel channel = new Channel();
    channel.setArguments(bundle);
    increaseSubChannelCount();
    String F_TAG = "SUB_CHANNEL_"+subChannelCount;
    Log.i("F_TAG NAME GOING TO BE ADDED ---->",F_TAG);
    String topFragmentName;
    if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0){
        topFragmentName = "ROOT_CHANNEL";
        ((Channel)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(topFragmentName)).pauseChannel();
        Log.i("PAUSED --------->", "ROOT_CHANNEL");
    }
    else{
        topFragmentName = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
        ((Channel)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(topFragmentName)).pauseChannel();
        Log.i("PAUSED --------->",topFragmentName);
    }

    transaction.hide(getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(topFragmentName));
    transaction.add(R.id.main_content_fragment, channel, F_TAG);
    transaction.addToBackStack(F_TAG);
    transaction.commit();
```